# Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I looked at other questions with the same problem, but I couldn't found a solution.
My `manifest.json`:

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "js/background.js" ],
   },
   "description": "...",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icons/128.png",
      "16": "icons/16.png",
      "48": "icons/48.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Name it!",
   "offline_enabled": false,
   "permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "https://www.youtube.com/*" ],
   "permissions": [ "https://www.youtube.com/*" ],
   "version": "1.0"

}
```

and my `background.js`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        var idid = details.url;
        var vid = idid.split("watch?v=");
        var akk = vid[1];
        if (akk.includes("&") && akk.includes("=")) {
            akk = akk.split("&")[0];
        }
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=xxx", false);
        xhr.send();
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        if(result.includes(akk)) {
            redirectUrl : "chrome-extension://"+window.location.hostname+"/html/block.html"
        }
    },
{urls: ["https://www.youtube.com/*"]},
["blocking"]);
```

I getting this Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined

What could be the problem?

Comment: I guess you've set a breakpoint in the background page script in devtools? If so, move it to a line inside the listener to avoid hitting a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=754976). Otherwise make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest.json may be the reason.

It has duplicate entries for "permissions". Try to remove the second one.

```
 "permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "https://www.youtube.com/*" ],
 "permissions": [ "https://www.youtube.com/*" ], // remove this one
```